# Collapse and expand deleted answers

Tags: support, feature-request, deleted-answers

It would be great if we could have options to collapse and expand the deleted answers.

For example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631168/how-to-disable-scrolling-of-nestedscrollview-for-example-when-there-is-no-more)  has many deleted answers and of course they are reordered below but when user scrolls downwards their attention is taken by low quality answers or any other of insufficient answers.

Collapsing/Expanding will bring more readability to the users with privilege of viewing deleted answers. I hope this is self explanatory, because I'm running out of words.